# Why does this Nested Select produce an error

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I get a "The Column BarMapping was specified multiple times for errors" in sql server. I cant figure out why. Heres what my code looks like:

```
SELECT @FooCount= COUNT(*) FROM 
(SELECT * FROM Download_Table dl
LEFT JOIN  @BarMapping sm
ON sm.cccID=dl.cccID  
WHERE DATEPART(hh, GETDATE())=DATEPART(hh, dl.DTS) AND sm.Store=73) errors
```

Comment: What is the point of the left join? You're going to get the same count as just a count against the download table with the where clause about the hour. Also note that adding sm.Store to the WHERE clause turns your left join into an inner join anyway.

Comment: Thats happened to me often, can you explain to me why the sm.Store turns the where clause to an inner join?

Comment: Because it can only match equality on rows where a value exists (comparing a null to 73 is going to be false, and drop the row out). So the only rows that could come back from that filter are rows that also matched the join condition. Still, even if you fix that, I still don't understand the point of the join - it's going to be the same count whether that join is there or not. Now, if you *meant* for it to be an inner join, that will be a different story.

Comment: Also, please don't use lazy and ambiguous shorthand for things like `hh`. It's not all that much harder to spell out `HOUR` but it makes your code much more self-documenting, and makes other code you write (or that other people learn from) immune from errors like this: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx

Comment: Couple things, Conceptually its a partial left join, i want all the rows tacked on to dl table where there is a matching cccID on BarMapping, but only the rows from BarMapping whos Store is 73

Comment: Second isnt hh required to get hour? its not a name, its a format for getting the hour out of a date... Am i wrong?

Comment: `hh` and `HOUR` are the same. However the lazy shorthand leads to other things being *assumed* to be the same, like `y` and `YEAR`. Please read the link I posted above to see why that can fail.

Comment: hrm, ill read the blog, but ill have to disagree with you there. hh:mm:ss is kind of standard.

Comment: I think you've absolutely, totally, 100% missed my point. M/D/Y is pretty standard too, but `DATEPART(Y, GETDATE())` doesn't produce what you might expect, now, does it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47358/discussion-between-ukemi-and-aaron-bertrand)

Comment: Im pretty sure i got -1 because mild disagreement with Aaron, which upsets me, because i was very tame and respectful. But what can you do.

Comment: Who knows why you got down-voted? Who knows who even down-voted you? Could be for a variety of reasons, could have been anyone, they may never even come back to this question (I only did because your comment actually pinged me). Don't let a down-vote ruin your day. They're imaginary Internet points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `select *` is getting the same field names from different tables.  And you are using it in a subquery.  Why not just do this:

```
SELECT @FooCount = COUNT(*)
FROM Download_Table dl LEFT JOIN 
     @BarMapping sm
     ON sm.cccID=dl.cccID  AND sm.Store = 73
WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()) = DATEPART(HOUR, dl.DTS);
```

You don't need the subquery at all.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like both the tables you are joining (Download_Table and the result of stored procedure BarMapping) have a common column which I guess is BarMapping which is causing the issue or confusion generating the error. So be specific by using table and column names or a simple fix would be to change Count(* ) to Count(column_name) to make it work